# How to process a dataframe or csv with millions of records and hundreds of columns?

Tags: python, dataframe, record

I have generated a data frame from a list with approximately 4 million records and 155 columns. Is there any way to produce training and test sets efficiently and faster? Preferrable coding language: python.

Comment: What doesn't work for you with sklearn's `train_test_split`? Trying this with a 400k sample matrix with 155 features works subsecond fast.

Comment: I am not using `train_test_split` for this. I have stored my data in such a way that it has two separate dataframes for training and testing. I'm not sure why there's a memory bottleneck here. AFAIK, my lists and dataframes have no bugs in them.